# Pseudo-code of a program

Tags: programming

I have written a code but I am facing a problem in pseudo-code that I am not able to change this code, so can anyone help me in translating the Arduino IDE program code to pseudo-code?

```cpp
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>        
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <SimpleTimer.h>
#include<DHT.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
char auth[] = "py0oKurvtk_Rv2GGkKtghpKqlxLQug8F";
char ssid[] = "Hostal1";
char pass[] = "shakajutt7867";
DHT dht(D4, DHT11);
SimpleTimer timer;
int Relay = D5;
int PIR = D3;
void sendSensor()
{
  float humi = dht.readHumidity();
  float temp = dht.readTemperature();
  int value = digitalRead(PIR);
  if (value == 1)
  {
  digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
  Serial.print("Detected");
  Serial.print('\n');
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("PIR = Detected");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("T: ");
  lcd.print(temp);
  lcd.setCursor(7,1);
  lcd.print(" H:");
  lcd.print(humi);

  }
  else if (value== 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
    Serial.print("Not Detected");
    Serial.print('\n');
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("PIR = Not Det");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("T:");
  lcd.print(temp);
  lcd.setCursor(7,1);
  lcd.print(" H:");
  lcd.print(humi);

  }
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V7, value);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V5, humi);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V6, temp);
  delay(1500);
}
void setup()
{
  pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIR, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(Relay,LOW);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  dht.begin();
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0); 
  timer.setInterval(1000L, sendSensor);
}
void loop()
{

  Blynk.run();
  timer.run();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem in writing this as pseudo code? Do you understand, what the code does (since this is essential to write it as pseudo code)?

Comment: what do you mean by `pseudo-code`?

Comment: You can format it by selecting the code and pressing ctrl-k

Comment: Although I know how the program line by line but how to write #INCLUDE libraries and there are many lines that I can't explain /?

Comment: Michel Keijzers ........... I couldn't get your point? How? Although ctrl+k doesn't work.

Comment: So it is more about understanding the program? If yes, then I can write an answer. What do you mean with "how to write #include libraries"? Pseudo code doesn't need any includes, since it is not compilable anyway. You just write, what the code should do on a level of higher abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

"Pseudo-code" isn't a programming language. It is just a term that we use when we write code that looks like code but can't be compiled, because it's half-English, half-code. You write pseudo code when you want to communicate to another human how code is supposed to work without getting bogged down in the details.